# Oracle Date Format Conversion Issue

Tags: oracle, date, datetime

Am at the end of my tether so hoping someone can help me!  I'm really new to Oracle, but do have a SQL background which is why I'm finding this so frustrating!

We have a system that runs Oracle at the back end.  I've got very limited access to the system and can only write select queries.

I've written a query that gets the data I want but the date format is coming out as `mm dd yyyy` what I need is `dd/mm/yyyy`

I ran `SELECT sysdate FROM dual` and that come back as:

```
SYSDATE
03 11 2015
```

So my select statement reads (action_date is the column in question)

```
Select username, action_date from adminview
```

I've tried everything I can think of to change the date format including:

```
to_date(action_date,'dd/mm/yyyy')

to_date(action_date,'dd/mm/yyyy','nls_language=English')

to_date(to_date(action_date,'mm dd yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

I've also tried `to_char` along the same lines.

Comment: Your column `action_date` is a date or varchar?

Comment: Try `alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY'`

Comment: I'm not sure Aramillo as I access it via a view.  I don't have access to any of the tables or data types. 

I can literally only run select statements, kordirko .... so can't run "alter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to format a `DATE` value, use `TO_CHAR()`:

```
SELECT username, TO_CHAR(action_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS action_date
  FROM adminview;
```

If it's not a `DATE` value, then you'll want to convert it to a `DATE` (based on what it currently looks like), then use `TO_CHAR()` to format.

Comment: You are a gem!  Thank you.  It was the "AS action_date" I was missing..... silly silly me!